# How to compare two columns in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have data in excel like below

```
columnA                         columnB     columnC 
Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)        500059      500059
Samskruthi S.O                  500088      
Sanath Nagar Colony S.O         500018      500018
```

if columnB and columnC are equal then i want the following result
then I have output like

```
columnA                         columnB     columnC   columnD 
Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)        500059      500059    Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)
Sanath Nagar Colony S.O         500018      500018    Sanath Nagar Colony S.O
```

Is it possible to do this in excel. If it is possible then please give me formula for my query

Thanks in advance

Comment: please answer this question

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 'if' condition would do what you want to achieve. Look at the following link for a basic understanding of how to use if - http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/if_function_sbs.htm

In your case you should do the following in column D -

```
=if(b1=c1,a1,"")
```